# Is there any way to draw EGL to /dev/fb1 instead of /dev/fb0 without copying data on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: c++, linux, opengl-es, raspberry-pi, egl

I found some information here, particularly that EGL doesn't use the /dev/fb* layers https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=58952

However, I would like to know if there is a way to swap /dev/fb0 and /dev/fb1, or to completely get rid of /dev/fb0?

/dev/fb0 is the hdmi output and /dev/fb1 is the SPI display

I don't need the hdmi display for anything, if there is a way to disable it permanently so SPI display becomes the primary fb0 display, that would work.

I have the following code to `mmap` the framebuffers, but they are different color depth, so I cannot memcpy it and copying pixel by pixel is painfully slow

Is there any better way at all to do this?

Thanks,

```
uint16_t *fbp0;
uint16_t *fbp1;
DISPMANX_DISPLAY_HANDLE_T display;
DISPMANX_RESOURCE_HANDLE_T resourceHandle;
VC_RECT_T rect;
struct fb_fix_screeninfo finfo;
uint32_t pixels;
const char *device = "/dev/fb1";
int fbfd = open(device, O_RDWR);
if (fbfd == -1) {printf("cannot open framebuffer device");return;}
if (ioctl(fbfd, FBIOGET_FSCREENINFO, &finfo) == -1) {printf("cannot get framebuffer fixed information");return;}
struct fb_var_screeninfo vinfo;
if (ioctl(fbfd, FBIOGET_VSCREENINFO, &vinfo) == -1) {printf("cannot get framebuffer variable information");return;}
if((vinfo.xres * 2) != finfo.line_length) {printf("assumption failed ... framebuffer lines are padded");return;}
if ((vinfo.xres % 16) != 0) {printf("framebuffer width must be a multiple of 16");return;}
if (vinfo.bits_per_pixel != 16){printf("framebuffer is not 16 bits per pixel");return;}
fbp1 = (uint16_t*)mmap(0,finfo.smem_len,PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED,fbfd,0);
if (fbp1 == MAP_FAILED){printf("cannot map framebuffer into memory");return;}
memset(fbp1, 0, finfo.smem_len);vc_dispmanx_resource_create(VC_IMAGE_RGB565,vinfo.xres,vinfo.yres,  &image_ptr);
device = "/dev/fb0";
fbfd = open(device, O_RDWR);
if (fbfd == -1) {printf("cannot open framebuffer device"); return;}
if (ioctl(fbfd, FBIOGET_FSCREENINFO, &finfo) == -1) {printf("cannot get framebuffer fixed information"); return;}
if (ioctl(fbfd, FBIOGET_VSCREENINFO, &vinfo) == -1) {printf("cannot get framebuffer variable information"); return;}
if ((vinfo.xres % 16) != 0) {printf("framebuffer width must be a multiple of 16"); return;}
fbp0 = (uint16_t*)mmap(0, finfo.smem_len, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fbfd, 0);
if (fbp0 == MAP_FAILED){printf("cannot map framebuffer into memory"); return;}
memset(fbp0, 0, finfo.smem_len);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another driver that I noticed uses fbcp (framebuffer copy). 
https://github.com/juj/fbcp-ili9341

It copies HDMI framebuffer to SPI display beautifully at 60hz and does not require the original SPI river installed and best of all it runs in userspace

Still not the solution I was looking for, but for anyone looking for this information try the driver above